# Determining location of element.style

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugins, slider

I am working on a website for a friend, using wordpress. It is located at [revere glass](http://revereglass.seeimpactdesign.com). I have installed the NextGen gallery, and am attempting to modify the size of the slideshow via the code, as the plugin editor does not seem to work properly.

When I use firebug to examine the layout, I see:

```
img src="http://revereglass.seeimpactdesign.com/wp-content/gallery/revere/big-instructor.jpg" style="height: 300px; width: 400px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; "
```

The class is .galleryview. I have attempted to edit the .js files, and galleryview.css, but I can't get the slider to change dimensions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so... what you wanna do? increase or decrease size?

Answer (score 0):

Check your markup. Make sure there are no inline styles. You can also try:

```
.galleryview {
     width: your-width-here !important;
}
```